# Android main package vs library module: who's app version data do I retain?

Tags: android, android-library

I was wondering where I should specify the versionCode/versionName in an Android library. Before I created the module, the app version data was stored in the manifest. Now I have two manifests, one for the main application (third-party) and one for the the library. I know that the main application's manifest gets higher priority during a merge, so I'm concerned that a the third-party's app version data will overwrite ours and cause issues.

Is this a problem I should be worried about? If so, what's the standard fix in this situation?

I'd be grateful for any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering where I should specify the versionCode/versionName in an Android library.

You don't. They do not have version codes or version names.

> If so, what's the standard fix in this situation?

Remove the version code and version name from the library module.

Comment: Thank you. That helps me understand it better.